# Trivial default constructor for std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, default-constructor

Couldn't `std::optional<T>` be [trivially default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor)?

Seems the only obstacle is the initialization of the `engaged` flag, but doesn't zero-initialization handle the situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would make it trivially default constructible, then in the following declaration:

```
std::optional<int> o;
```

the `engaged` flag (or the equivalent internal representation) would be **uninitialized** (1).

True, the user can use the correct initialization:

```
std::optional<int> o{};
```

But the point of encapsulation is to design your class in such a way that no matter what legal code someone writes with your class, an object of this class will **always be in a valid state** (2). I.e. you need to guarantee that no matter how your object is being manipulated it will never "break".

---

(1) except if it is global/static, in which case the internal representation of engaged would be zero-initialized (thanks to [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) for pointing it out)

(2) please note that here by valid state I mean a state where all values of data members make sense (they satisfy the class invariants). For instance the internal size of a vector correctly reflects the number of objects held, the engaged flag correctly reflects if the optional holds or not the underlying object, etc.

Comment: Unless `o` were static/thread_local, in which case the internal representation of `engaged` would be zero-initialized.

Comment: @NicolBolas true, added